# debugging arp requests over vlan

Tags: arp, interface, tcpdump

We have a chain of switches configured for vlan 13, let's call them switch1, switch2 and switch3
No, somewhere on this chain the arp requests get lost. I can run tcpdump on these switches. Running just `sudo tcpdump -n host 192.168.42.1` shows that switch1 and switch2 get the arp requests but switch3 doesn't.

I'd like to further isolate the problem to see if the problem is switch2 or switch3. Can I tell tcpdump to only listen for outgoing arp requests on one specific interface? I tried with `sudo tcpdump -e -i et6` but I don't see the arp requests.

**Update**:

here's the port config of the three switches. The layout (syntax `incoming_port#switch#outgoing_port`):

`fw1 - 6#switch1#45 - 45#switch2#51 - fiber - 41#switch3 - fw2`

```
! switch 1: incoming

interface Ethernet6
   switchport access vlan 13
   spanning-tree portfast

! switch 1: outgoing

interface Ethernet45
   channel-group 60 mode active

interface Port-Channel60
   switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-3,5-4094
   switchport mode trunk
   mlag 16

! switch 2: incoming

interface Ethernet45
   switchport mode trunk
   channel-group 60 mode active
!

interface Port-Channel60
   switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-3,5-4094
   switchport mode trunk
!

! switch 2: outgoing

interface Ethernet51
   mtu 9000
   switchport access vlan 8
   switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3,5-14,101-110,112-120
   switchport mode trunk
!

! switch 3: incoming

interface Ethernet51
   mtu 9000
   switchport access vlan 8
   switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3,5-14,101-110,112-120
   switchport mode trunk
!
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information. What are the switch models and configurations?

Comment: By the way, switches are transparent devices, and they don't get involved in ARP. ARP is between hosts to resolve a layer-3 address to a layer-2 address, and switches don't know anything about layer-3. ARP requests are layer-2 broadcasts, and ARP replies are layer-2 unicasts.

Comment: I know that arp requests are any/multicast on layer 2 and that switches are also layer 2. Only `tcpdump` seems misplaced. If there are better tools for that, I'd interested to know

Comment: We need a diagram to see how these switches are connected to each other and the hosts.  Where are you running tcpdump from?

Comment: What is the outgoing port of switch 3? The configuration of that port could be the problem. Otherwise, you should give the full switch configurations.

Comment: @RonTrunk I added a "diagram". I ran the tcpdump on all of them, on switch1 and switch2 the arp packages are visible, on switch3 not. There's a fiber in between and potentially also some layer2 devices but those *should* not do any filtering at all

Comment: @RonMaupin IMO the outgoing port of switch 3 is not relevant as the arp packages don't make it to switch 3

Comment: How can you tell that? As far as I can tell from the provided information, the ARP request could be getting to switch 3, but not out the switch port. There are other configurations which could have an effect on this, and you have not included all the switch configurations. You are asking us for help, and you should provide what we need to help. I think that if you could do it yourself and know what to look at, you wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks a lot for your patience. In fact I don't know which the outgoing port is. There are several paths to the firewall from this point on. Also, I'm a beginner in networking and our network pro is on vacations. I run tcpdump looking for arp packets. I see them on switch 1, switch 2 but not on switch 3. That's why I think the problem lies in switch 2 outgoing or switch 3 incoming port, not on the switch 3 outgoing port. Do I mess something up here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The issue was indeed on the outgoing port as suggested in the comments above. Whatever it's worth a few findings along the way of solving this problem:

1. first understand the network topology. Nobody can help you before you did that exercise yourself. You cannot ask for punctual help if you don't understand the big picture first
2. no, there doesn't seem a way to see if an arp packet is sent to a specific interface
3. on some switches tcpdump didn't show the arp packages. [This thread](https://eos.arista.com/forum/tcpdump-doesnt-show-traffic/) explains that only packets show up that go through the cpu of the switch. This is the case if the packets originate from the switch or are destined for the switch or the advanced tracking is turned on (which was probably my case as the switches where it did show up are running on version 4.15.x of Aristas EOS and the ones which didn't show the arp packages were running 4.12.x)
4. for debugging vlans it's helpful to set up vlan interfaces along the way. In my case the Arista switch supports setting up an endpoint with an ip address like this:

   ```
   interface Vlan13
     ip address 192.168.42.17/24
   ```

doing this lets you do e.g. `arping 192.168.42.2 -I vlan13` or simply `ping 192.168.42.2` (the switch knows that this IP address is configured on vlan 13 and sends the pings over this vlan)